# CouchDB put data in correct database

Tags: javascript, database, couchdb, pouchdb

I've got CouchDB setup with Couchperuser. Locally I use PouchDB.
I'm building a mobile application with Cordova. It's about a todo list. with login, so users have there own list.
When I create a new user it automatically makes a new database for this user.
now, when that user is logged in and adds new todo's to his list, they go in the main database because I use :

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/main', {skipSetup: true});
```

What I want to achieve is that the todo created by the specific user goes into his database. for example:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/userdb-41646d696e32', {skipSetup: true});
```

How can I automatically do this? so the ***var db = the users database***?

I've looked around the internet but could not find anything about this.
Hope someone can help me with this scenario.

EDIT:
I'll add the code that I use for adding the todo:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/main', {skipSetup: true});
function addToDoItem() {
      //get info
      var toDoTitle = document.getElementById('toDoTitle').value;
      var toDoDescr = document.getElementById('toDoDesc').value;

    var addItem = {
      _id: new Date().toISOString(),
      title: ToDotitle,
      description: ToDoDescr
    };
    db.put(addItem ).then(function (result){
      console.log("Added to the database");
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(function (err){
      console.log("someting bad happened");
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? Why don't you use something like `var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/' + userId);` where userId is the Id of a user?

Comment: i mean something like that. The database name looks like this: userdb-41646d696e32. that is the hax value of 'admin'username. how do I get that db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out, this is the way to fix it. thought of it already but seemed a bit of a cheap solution. anyway, this is the only code example I found on the internet.

```
dbs.remote.private = pouchDB(DATABASE.URL + "userdb-" + _convertToHex(username), {
    auth: {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }
});
```